# If |G/H|=4 then G is union of three proper subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If |G/H|=4 and G/H  is not cyclic then G is union of three proper subgroups. I understand that there are three subgroups of order two in the G/H group. Consequently, in the group G there are three subgroups A, B, C of index two which in them pass under the homomorphism. But how to prove that G is a union of the subgroups A, B, and C

Comment: If $G/H$ is cyclic, it has only one subgroup of order $2$...

Comment: yes, but I meant that G/H is not cyclic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If $A,B,C$ are subsets in $G$, then
$$|A \cup B \cup C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B| - |A \cap C| - |B \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C|.$$

$G/H\cong K_4$, so you know that by the Correspondence theorem that there exists subgroups $A,B,C$ in $G$ such that $|A|=|B|=|C|=2|H|$ and $|A\cap B|=|B\cap C|=|C\cap A|=|A\cap B\cap C|=|H|$, so what can you say about $|A\cup B\cup C|$?

Comment: Why do you think that |A∩B|=|B∩C|=|C∩A|=|A∩B∩C|=|H| ? We can say that A∩B  is a subgrop A and B .

Comment: @Cat you can pick three proper subgroups in the quotient groups whose union is the entire Q/H. The quotient is the Klein 4 group. You pick three subgroups in Q/H such that each two intersect trivially. They correspond to three subgroups of Q whose union is entire Q. You prove this by correspondence theorem and by counting the elements in each subgroup.

Comment: The point is that the intersection of each two of these three proper subgroups in G is H, just like the intersection of each two proper subgroups of G/H is the identity.

Comment: let V4=K∪L∪M and π−1(K)=A, π−1(L)= B andπ−1(M)=C. Let  π(G) = V4  but that does not mean that  G=π−1(K)∪π−1(L)∪π−1(M)

Comment: By the correspondence theorem, the three different proper subgroups of $K_4$ correspond to three different proper subgroups $K,L,M$ of $G$ that contain $H$. Each of $K,L,M$ are different and are of index 2 in $G$. The intersection of each of $K,L,M$ must be a proper subgroup of $G$. The intersections must be index 2 in $K,L$ or $M$ (K=L otherwise, for example, which leads to contradiction).

Comment: I agree that in Γ there are three distinct proper subgroups intersecting only with respect to the identity element. But why the intersection of two of them must coincide with the kernel of the homomorphism and can not be a proper subgroup of the kernel ?

Comment: @Cat The [correspondence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem_(group_theory)) states that: Because $G$ is a group and $H$ is a normal subgroup of $H$, then there is a one-to-one correspondence between **all the subgroups of $G$ that contain $H$** to **all the subgroups of $G/H$**. Are you familiar with this theorem? $K,L,M$ are subgroups of $G$ that contain $H$ while the three non-trivial proper subgroups of $K_{4}$ are isomorphic to the non-trivial proper subgroups of $H$.

Comment: my question is that if the intersection of subgroups is contained in H and does not coincide with H (not the H subgroup of intersection of subgroups)

Comment: Yes, I know with the correspondence theorem. By this theorem we can say that the intersection of two proper subgroups should not be greater than H, but this theorem does not say that if the intersection is less than H. If the intersection of two subgroups is contained in the kernel of the homomorphism then under the homomorphism the intersection is mapped to the identity element  of the homomorphic image

Comment: @Cat By the correspondence theorem, the $K,L,M$ we're looking for (subgroups of $G$) are by definition, subgroups of $G$ that contain **$H$**, i.e. $H\subseteq K$, $H\subseteq L$, $H\subseteq M$.  The intersection of these $K$, $L$ and $M$ must all contain $H$.  Therefore, the intersections of these proper subgroups cannot be a proper subgroup of $H$.

Comment: @Cat "By this theorem we can say that the intersection of two proper subgroups should not be greater than H" On the contrary, the intersection of two subgroups found in this manner, by definition, must be a supergroup of $H$ ($H$ or larger).